# From where retrieve the list?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have for example 2 entitis : Client, Reservation.
one to many bidirectional relationship.
One Client to Many reservation where the reservation is the owner.
When i want to get all the reservations for one client, How can i do that?
Maybe to find the client by query and from the object use client.getReservations()?
Or maybe make a query to find the reservations where id.

Client class:

```
ublic class Client extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();

    public Client() {

    }

    public Client(String fullName, String phoneNumber, String email, String address) {

        super(fullName, phoneNumber, email, address);
    }

    public List<Reservation> getReservations() {
        return reservations;
    }

    public void addReservation(Reservation reservation) {
        this.reservations.add(reservation);
        reservation.setClient(this);
    }

    public void removeReservation(Reservation reservation) {
        this.getReservations().remove(reservation);
        reservation.setClient(null);

    }
```

Reservation class:

```
public class Reservation {

    // --- attributs ---
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "reservation_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_to_supply")
    private Date dateToSupply;

    @Column(name = "total_sum")
    private double totalSum;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Both methods will work, so...

Comment: Just keep in mind that using `client.getReservations()` directly will result in two queries - one for the `Client` and another one for the `reservations`. You'll also load a bunch of `Client`-specific data I'm assuming you don't need

Comment: So if i call method getAllClients() the reservations will load too?

Comment: Why would they? `@OneToMany` associations are lazy by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one to many relationships, while you load Client in your example, it will load client with all reservations. So as mentioned client.getReservations(). Will get all the reservation with that particular client.